# How can I include this code within my website?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering how I could embed this below into my website code. As I'm a beginner I was confused on how I can include this I'm just use to using the 12 grid system and never came across adding this to my website before.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```

```css
.one {
  background: #F1E05A;
}

.two {
  background: #563D7C;
}

.three {
  background: #E34C26;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>


<div id="Sections">
 <div class="section one"></div>
 <div class="section two"></div>
 <div class="section three"></div>
</div>
```

**FULL SITE CODE**

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="#">Home</a>
             </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                 </li>

                 <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
         <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
       </div>
       <!-- /.container-fluid -->
     </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "embed this [code] into bootstrap"?

Comment: Just use it on your site ? ... Aside `$('#fullpage')`must be `$('#Sections')` on your snippet

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include styles and scripts inline as below. Best practice would be to put these into their own files though. This allows you to better manage code and separate responsibility.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <style>
            .one {
                background: #F1E05A;
            }
    
            .two {
                background: #563D7C;
            }
    
            .three {
                background: #E34C26;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Sections">
            <div class="section one">Foo</div>
            <div class="section two">Bar</div>
            <div class="section three">Baz</div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
    
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#Sections').fullpage();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've also targeted the `#Sections` div for the JQuery function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post. I updated my original post.

Comment: Thanks for your time and response it was very helpful. I seemed off over complicated this task seems quite easy now you showed me. I marked your answer as the correction answer. If you don't can you help me resize section 1/2 therefore, it fits the full size of the page, not only just like this. http://i.imgur.com/9Oii1D4.png

Comment: @AJKCJDC the `.container` classes in bootstrap will do that. If you make sure it's not contained within one of those divs, it should fill the width. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is how to display all of these things in an html page, this should get you started.  You could also move your styling into a custom css file.

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    .one {
        background: #F1E05A;
    }

    .two {
        background: #563D7C;
    }

    .three {
        background: #E34C26;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Sections">
    <div class="section one"><span>Color 1</span></div>
    <div class="section two"><span>Color 2</span></div>
    <div class="section three"><span>Color 3</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post. I updated my original post.